# Sum of two invertible matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If A and B are two n x n invertible matrices, would the matrix result from A+B be invertible?

I think it would because for a matrix to be invertible its determinant would have to be greater than 0, and if you add the determinants of two matrices greater than 0 you would have to get a non zero answer. But is there any way to prove this?

Comment: 1+(-1)=0$\phantom{}$.

Answer (score 7):

The answer is generally no.  For instance, consider
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}, \quad B = \pmatrix{-1&0\\0&-1}
$$

Comment: I see, thank you for your explanation!